# How to launch relevant page of the app based on OS language and country of the device in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, internationalization

I have 3 versions of my app: Latvian, Russian and English and I want to launch them based on OS language and country of a device. For example, if phone system language is Russian and country that was set in this device is Latvia, then MyHomeRUPage(Russian version of homepage) is launched rather than MyHomePage(Latvian version of homepage). Is this even possible with structure that I have and if so, how to realize this?

Code segment that is responsible for application launch:

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent, // Make the status bar transparent
    statusBarIconBrightness:
        Brightness.light, // Use light icons on the status bar
  ));
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => MyAppState(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Assistant',
        theme: ThemeData(
          useMaterial3: true,
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepOrange),
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
        ),
        home: MyHomePage(),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Tried to google that problem, but seems that solutions listed there doesn't suit me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the difference between the three versions is only in translation, i rather that you implement localization in your project, instead of having three different files for every page in the application.

Use this docs to find out how: [Localization in Flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20Flutter%20only%20provides,113%20languages%20and%20language%20variants).

if you insist on using your way,
you have to implement a method to know the device locale and the link provided above gives you the way

```
Locale deviceLocale = window.locale;
```

then you should put an if statement in your **MyApp** class to switch to the desired page based on the result of the **Locale**

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent, // Make the status bar transparent
    statusBarIconBrightness:
        Brightness.light, // Use light icons on the status bar
  ));
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Locale deviceLocale = window.locale;
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => MyAppState(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Assistant',
        theme: ThemeData(
          useMaterial3: true,
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepOrange),
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
        ),
        home: getHomePage(deviceLocale),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      ),
    );
  }
Widget getHomePage(Locale deviceLocale){
if(deviceLocale.languageCode=="ru"){
      return MyHomeRUPage();
    }else{
      return MyHomePage();
    }
}
}
```